# Best word for blunt, honest humor where you say something shocking to get a laugh?

Tags: synonyms, humor, irony

What's the best word for the type of humor where you state something very honestly and bluntly with the intent to be a little shocking and a little humorous? Potentially because people don't expect a certain behavior to be pointed out so bluntly? It's not sarcasm because you are telling the truth, right, not the opposite of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

That description brings to mind "bluff" as an adjective to describe that kind of humor:

> **bluff** *adj*
>   1. good-naturedly direct, blunt, or frank; heartily outspoken.
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bluff)</sub>

Bluff humor: it's honest, it's blunt, it's frank—but it doesn't have the negative qualities of some other, sharper adjectives, and it doesn't shade toward sarcasm or mockery. And such outspokenness can certainly be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

**mordant**  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mordant)  adj

> **Mordant humor** is very critical and often mocks someone or something; harshly ironic or sinister

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/122153?rskey=UfvvjX&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

**mordant**

> 1. Of a person, his or her **wit**, a remark, etc.: having or showing a sharply critical quality; biting, caustic, incisive.

As in:

> "A mordant sense of humor informs many of the scenes, as when Georg
>   asks for a room and is told by the landlady that he must produce
>   papers proving his travel plans."  Seattle TimesApr 2, 2019

Comment: +1...I keep my commitments.